# Trigger event upon trigger completion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of events created already that contain numerous steps.  For example:

`$("#CourseID").change` will automatically gather information about a course.  It also creates a series of checkboxes for each hole on the course.  It then checks each box by default.

I also have a function `$("#ClearAll").click` linked to a button click.  This will clear all the checkboxes.

I now have a third event `$("#SetDate").change` that i need to call both of the above:

```
$("#CourseID").trigger('click')
$("#ClearAll").trigger('click')
```

because after this happens, I need to go through an array of holes and have each one check.

My problem is that it is running `$("#ClearAll").trigger('click')` prior to `$("#CourseID").trigger('click')` completing.  Thus, the checkboxes are not completing.

Any insight would be appreciated.   I'm fairly new to jQuery so please explain thoroughly.

Comment: Based on your description this should not happen. However, without being able to look at the actual code and having no idea what you are actually doing -- it's very hard to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: make an option on $("#CourseID").change to accept a _then_ function, which if passed, gets called from the bottom. then pass $("#CourseID").change to the new handler from the third handler mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use promises or defer. These are used in situation like this where you need one function to be called before another. [deferred.promise](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.    The $("#CourseID").change event had an ajax call.   By using `$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
      $("#ClearAll").trigger('click');
}`

It then waited for the completion of the CourseID function and the checkboxes would be cleared.

Jon - sorry I didn't post the code, but without the 1500 lines of code it would not have made sense.